# Is there a way to put a clickable hyperlink in an operator's tooltip?

Tags: python, interface

I'm curious, is there any way to easily add a clickable hyperlink to an Operator's tooltip through the Python API?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, no. Blender itself doesn't contain the code necessary to parse text strings and notice that a mouse hit is in a URL.

Comment: @MartyFouts Okay, cool, good to know. Do you suppose this could easily be coded in Python, or would it be pretty involved?

Comment: You can add a manual link to the operator's context or you can invoke `bpy.ops.wm.url_open()` with event like `shift+LMB`